# Creating View from Related Child Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, sql-view

I have the following general table structure (forgive the United States-centric carmakers in my contrived example):

```
CREATE TABLE Car (
    [Id] int PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE Ford (
    [FordId] int PRIMARY KEY, --also a foreign key on Car
    [Model]  nvarchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE Chevy (
    [ChevyId] int PRIMARY KEY, --also a foreign key on Car
    [Model]  nvarchar(max)
)
```

I am wanting to create a view on top of these tables so that I can retrieve all Fords and Chevys and just have a generated column in the view that tells me the make. My first stab was this:

```
SELECT 
    c.CarId,
    case when f.FordId is not null then 'Ford' else 'Chevy' end 
FROM Car as c
LEFT JOIN Ford as f on c.Id = f.FordId
LEFT JOIN Chevy as ch on c.Id = ch.ChevyId
WHERE (f.FordId is not null or ch.ChevyId is not null)
```

But that leaves a bad taste in my mouth and I am concerned about performance. Would I be better off retrieving all the Fords and Chevys in separate CTE values and just performing a union on them? Am I on the wrong track entirely? I will also be needing to include the Model column (as well as a few other columns common to the two child tables), which would obviously make my view turn into a giant series of case statements. What is the "proper" way to handle such a situation?

**EDIT**: Thought I should add that this schema already exists so changing the underlying tables is not possible.

Comment: is it possible to have `FordId` from `Ford` to be equal 1 and `ChevyId` from `Chevy` to be equal 1? :)

Comment: Ha, nope, thankfully that is not possible. Each Id value will be unique.

Comment: and how do you prevent it? Does SQL Server optimizer knows that this is not possible? If not, then your union could be slow if you'll be using your view in joins

Comment: That's an excellent question. The way it works is that when a Ford is created, an entry is first added to the Car table, then the SCOPE_IDENTITY() from that add is used to add to the Ford or Chevy table. This system is nearing 10 years old and has many questionable aspects, as you can tell. The comment about slowdowns since this really isn't discoverable is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's try to see pros and cons of each of 2 approaches:

```
create view vw_Car1
as
  SELECT 
      c.Id,
      case when f.FordId is not null then 'Ford' else 'Chevy' end as Maker,
      coalesce(f.Model, ch.Model) as Model
  FROM Car as c
  LEFT JOIN Ford as f on c.Id = f.FordId
  LEFT JOIN Chevy as ch on c.Id = ch.ChevyId
  WHERE (f.FordId is not null or ch.ChevyId is not null);

create view vw_Car2
as
  select FordId as id, 'Ford' as Maker, Model from Ford
  union all
  select ChevyId as id, 'Chevy' as Maker, Model from Chevy;
```

The first one is better when you use it in joins, especially if you'll not using all of your columns. For example, let's say you have a view when you're using your `vw_Car`:

```
create table people (name nvarchar(128), Carid int);

insert into people
select 'John', 1 union all
select 'Paul', 2;

create view vw_people1
as
select
    p.Name, c.Maker, c.Model
from people as p
   left outer join vw_Car1 as c on c.ID = p.CarID;

create view vw_people2
as
select
    p.Name, c.Maker, c.Model
from people as p
   left outer join vw_Car2 as c on c.ID = p.CarID;
```

Now, if you want to do simple select:

```
select Name from vw_people1;

select Name from vw_people2;
```

First one would be simple select from `people` (`vw_Car1` will not be queried at all). Second one will be more complex - `Ford` and `Chevy` will be both queried.
You could think that first approach is better, but let's try another query:

```
select *
from vw_people1
where Maker = 'Ford' and Model = 'Fiesta';

select *
from vw_people2
where Maker = 'Ford' and Model = 'Fiesta';
```

Here second one will be faster, especially if you have index on `Model` column.

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07e58/2) - see query plans of these queries.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So if I am going to be, generally, retrieving based on some where criteria in the view, I'd be better off going with the union strategy?

Comment: @ledbutter well it depends on your queries, I think there's no silver bullet especially if you cannot change your schema. In your case you could move Model into Cars table and use join strategy also (if you can change schema). If you go with union strategy, keep an eye on joining views using your tables.