# Alternatives to Multiple Case Statements for Same Column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

To match up some new schema to old, I'm having to do some ugly contortions that I figure could be done in a better way. For reference, I asked another question about this match-up process here: [Creating View from Related Child Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662247/creating-view-from-related-child-tables)

I've placed a simplified example in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7868/2/0) but the gist of it is, that the only way I can see reconciling these two different schemas is to do two case statements on the same value, something like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN n.FooBarStatusId = 1 OR n.FooBarStatusId = 2 
            THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END as [IsFoo],
    CASE
        WHEN n.FooBarStatusId = 2
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END as [IsBar]
from Parent p
left join OldStuff o on p.ParentId = o.ParentId
left join NewStuff n on p.ParentId = n.ParentId
```

Is there a better and/or more efficient way of accomplishing the same thing? These case statements could be hit hundreds of times in a given query and I'm concerned about this specific logic.

I've thought about extracting this specific logic out (it is part of a larger query to build a view) into a temp table or perhaps even a table-valued function, but even still I can't come up with a way around using multiple case statements.

Comment: They look fine to me.  What is your specific concern about them? (and FYI, they are Case *Expressions*, not Case Statements).

Comment: `case when n.FooBarStatusId in ( 1, 2 ) then 1 else 0 end` may be clearer.

Comment: @RBarryYoung it may be a naive concern, but I am annoyed/concerned about doing two different evaluations of the same column value. Regarding expressions vs statements, my predominant experience with C# showed through there.

Comment: @HABO thanks, I agree that that looks clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just corrected grammar...**

I found another solution:

```
select 
 p.Name,
 ISNULL(o.IsFoo, CONVERT(BIT, n.FooBarStatusId)) as [IsFoo],
 ISNULL(o.IsBar, CONVERT(BIT, n.FooBarStatusId * (n.FooBarStatusId - 1))) as [IsBar],
from Parent p
left join OldStuff o on p.ParentId = o.ParentId
left join NewStuff n on p.ParentId = n.ParentId
```

The only one arithmetic solution could be slow:

```
select 
 p.Name,
 ISNULL(o.IsFoo, CAST( (n.FooBarStatusId % 0.35) * 4 AS int)) AS [IsFoo],
 ISNULL(o.IsBar, n.FooBarStatusId/2) [IsBar]
from Parent p
left join OldStuff o on p.ParentId = o.ParentId
left join NewStuff n on p.ParentId = n.ParentId
```

Personally, I do not like to use the division, because of could be involved floating point operations, that way, it would be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

As you have two columns, you *will* need two expressions... but they might not have to be `CASE` expressions. Reading your question, I get the impressions that the only possible values in the column are 0,1,2, and that this is an `int` type? If that's correct, you can use arithmetic rather than boolean logic to get what you need. Try this:

```
CAST( (n.FooBarStatusId % .35) * 4 AS int) AS [IsFoo],
n.FooBarStatusId/2 [IsBar]
```

Comment: That seems even more complex/difficult to understand than the case statements. A very interesting idea though.

Comment: For the first expression I agree with you on the readability grounds, though I prefer the arithmetic in the 2nd. I expect, though, that both of these will perform **way** better than CASE if you have a lot of rows.